# Fill ConverterParameter with DateTime info

Tags: c#, wpf, datepicker

I am trying to bind DatePicker.DisplayDate to TextBox.Text property. The Binding should work TwoWays and should display and/or change current month. Means when I enter another month name in TextBox the DatePicker should follow. However the DatePicker should only change its month.

For example if DatePicker is open and is currently displaying 18. February 2018 and I enter in TextBox "December" the DatePicker should change to 18. December 2018.

Here is code:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <converters:DateTimeToStringConverter x:Key="dateTimeToStringConverter"/>
</Window.Resources>
<StackPanel>
    <TextBox Text="{Binding ElementName=datePicker, Path=DisplayDate, Converter={StaticResource dateTimeToStringConverter}, StringFormat={}{0:D}}"/>
    <DatePicker x:Name="datePicker"/>
</StackPanel>
```

This is the converter:

```
public class DateTimeToStringConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture.DateTimeFormat.GetMonthName(((DateTime)value).Month);
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        // how to just change month of datepicker but let day and year stay?
        return value;
    }
}
```

I think I might need to use ConverterParameter to somehow retrieve information about what is DatePicker's current day and year. The month is coming from TextBox.

Any ideas guys?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the XAML as follows

```
  <StackPanel>
        <TextBox 
            Text="{Binding ElementName=datePicker, Path=DisplayDate, Converter={StaticResource dateTimeToStringConverter}, StringFormat={}{0:MMMM}}"/>
        <DatePicker x:Name="datePicker"/>
    </StackPanel>
```

and converter as follows :

```
public class DateTimeToStringConverter : IValueConverter
{
    private DateTime currentDisplayDate;
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        currentDisplayDate = (DateTime)value;
        return value;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
       bool flag;
            DateTime output;
            flag = DateTime.TryParseExact(currentDisplayDate.Day + " " + value.ToString().Trim() + " " + currentDisplayDate.Year, "d MMMM yyyy",
                                            CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,DateTimeStyles.None,out output);

        /* To handle month last day difference */
           if(!flag)
            flag = DateTime.TryParseExact(1 + " " + value.ToString().Trim() + " " + currentDisplayDate.Year, "d MMMM yyyy",
                                            CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None, out output);
       return flag ? output : currentDisplayDate;  

    }
}
```